# check box value not appears for false case

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

How can we handle check box in xeditable, currently having values as Y or N to represent true or false respectively. In case of unchecked there is no value displayed on the page.

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox" ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N" ng-checked="checkbox == 'Y'" />
```

this is the Issue http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/260/

Comment: Is this what you want? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/261/)

Comment: Why there is not checked on load ?

Comment: Can't we set initial value ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/1/

Comment: Can you modify the fiddle with Y or N. This fiddle with 0 or 1 had seen already

Comment: got exception "ngModel:constexpr] Expected constant expression for `ngTrueValue`, but saw `Y`."

Comment: I believe this is what you want [link](http://jsfiddle.net/69CAF/264/).Let me know if it is correct, will post it as an answer.

Comment: do u have any idea why this error -  angular.js:12477 Error: [ngModel:constexpr] Expected constant expression for `ngTrueValue`, but saw `Y`.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ngModel/constexpr?p0=ngTrueValue&p1=Y
    at http://localhost:8080/DAC/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at parseConstantExpr (http://localhost:8080/DAC/angular.js:22006:13)
    at checkboxInputType (http://localhost:8080/DAC/r/angular.js:22015:19) 
    <input type="checkbox" name="activeYn" required="required" ng-true-value="Y" ng-false-value="N" class="editable-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="$data">

Comment: `ngTrueValue` is by default of type expression.That's why in the last fiddle i made a change, checked it?